# How to use multiple Zookeeper with distributed state machine?

Tags: apache-zookeeper, spring-statemachine

I'm trying to use distributed states in my application with zookeeper just like [in the Spring document](https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-statemachine/1.2.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/sm-distributed.html), with only one difference. My application works fine with one zookeeper but I need multiple zookeeper address. Here is my configuration:

```
import jpapersistsm.enums.Events;
import jpapersistsm.enums.States;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.apache.curator.framework.CuratorFramework;
import org.apache.curator.framework.CuratorFrameworkFactory;
import org.apache.curator.retry.ExponentialBackoffRetry;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.statemachine.config.EnableStateMachineFactory;
import org.springframework.statemachine.config.StateMachineConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.statemachine.config.StateMachineFactory;
import org.springframework.statemachine.config.builders.StateMachineConfigurationConfigurer;
import org.springframework.statemachine.config.builders.StateMachineStateConfigurer;
import org.springframework.statemachine.config.builders.StateMachineTransitionConfigurer;
import org.springframework.statemachine.data.jpa.JpaPersistingStateMachineInterceptor;
import org.springframework.statemachine.data.jpa.JpaStateMachineRepository;
import org.springframework.statemachine.ensemble.StateMachineEnsemble;
import org.springframework.statemachine.listener.StateMachineListener;
import org.springframework.statemachine.listener.StateMachineListenerAdapter;
import org.springframework.statemachine.persist.StateMachineRuntimePersister;
import org.springframework.statemachine.service.DefaultStateMachineService;
import org.springframework.statemachine.service.StateMachineService;
import org.springframework.statemachine.state.State;
import org.springframework.statemachine.zookeeper.ZookeeperStateMachineEnsemble;

import java.util.EnumSet;

@Slf4j
@Configuration
@EnableStateMachineFactory
public class JpaPersistStateMachineConfiguration extends StateMachineConfigurerAdapter<States, Events> {

    @Autowired
    public JpaStateMachineRepository jpaStateMachineRepository;

    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JpaPersistStateMachineConfiguration.class);

    @Override
    public void configure(StateMachineStateConfigurer<States, Events> states) throws Exception{

        states
                .withStates()
                .initial(States.ORDERED)
                .end(States.PAYED)
                .end(States.CANCELLED)
                .states(EnumSet.allOf(States.class));
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(StateMachineTransitionConfigurer<States,Events> transitions) throws Exception {

        transitions
                .withExternal().source(States.ORDERED).target(States.ASSEMBLED).event(Events.assemble).and()
                .withExternal().source(States.ASSEMBLED).target(States.DELIVERED).event(Events.deliver).and()
                .withExternal().source(States.DELIVERED).target(States.PAYED).event(Events.payment_received).and()
                .withExternal().source(States.ORDERED).target(States.CANCELLED).event(Events.cancel).and()
                .withExternal().source(States.ASSEMBLED).target(States.CANCELLED).event(Events.cancel).and()
                .withExternal().source(States.DELIVERED).target(States.CANCELLED).event(Events.cancel);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(StateMachineConfigurationConfigurer<States,Events> config) throws Exception{

        config
                .withDistributed()
                    .ensemble(stateMachineEnsemble())
                    .and()
                .withPersistence()
                    .runtimePersister(stateMachineRuntimePersister())
                    .and()
                .withConfiguration()
                    .autoStartup(true);

    }

    @Bean
    public StateMachineEnsemble<States, Events> stateMachineEnsemble() throws Exception {
        return new ZookeeperStateMachineEnsemble<States, Events>(curatorClient(), "/app");
    }

    @Bean
    public CuratorFramework curatorClient() throws Exception {
        CuratorFramework client = CuratorFrameworkFactory
                .builder()
                .defaultData(new byte[0])
                .retryPolicy(new ExponentialBackoffRetry(1000, 3))
                .connectString("localhost:2181,localhost:2182,localhost:2183")
                .build();
        client.start();
        return client;
    }

    @Bean
    public StateMachineRuntimePersister<States,Events,String> stateMachineRuntimePersister(){
        return new JpaPersistingStateMachineInterceptor<>(jpaStateMachineRepository);
    }

    @Bean
    public StateMachineService<States,Events> stateMachineService (
            StateMachineFactory<States,Events> stateMachineFactory,
            StateMachineRuntimePersister<States,Events,String> stateMachineRuntimePersister){

        return new DefaultStateMachineService<>(stateMachineFactory, stateMachineRuntimePersister);
    }

    @Bean
    public StateMachineListener<States, Events> listener() {

        return new StateMachineListenerAdapter<States, Events>() {
            @Override
            public void stateChanged(State<States, Events> from, State<States, Events> to) {
                logger.info("*** listener: in state changed");
                if (from == null) logger.info("*** state machine initialised in state {}", to.getId());
                else logger.info("*** state changed from {} to {}", from.getId(), to.getId());
            }
        };
    }
}
```

And my REST Controller class is:

```
import jpapersistsm.enums.Events;
import jpapersistsm.enums.States;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.statemachine.StateMachine;
import org.springframework.statemachine.listener.StateMachineListener;
import org.springframework.statemachine.service.StateMachineService;
import org.springframework.util.ObjectUtils;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.Map;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/jpapersist")
public class RestServiceController {

    @Autowired
    public StateMachineService<States, Events> stateMachineService;

    @Autowired
    public StateMachineListener listener;

    public StateMachine<States, Events> stateMachine;
    public Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RestServiceController.class);

    @RequestMapping(value="/init", method= RequestMethod.POST)
    public void init(@RequestBody Map<String,String> parameters){
        logger.info("\n*** inside of state machine controller : INIT ");
        try {
            stateMachine = getStateMachine(parameters.get("guid"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        logger.info("\n*** state machine initialized to state: {}", stateMachine.getState().getId().name());
    }

    /***
    Synchronized method to obtain persisted state machine from database.
     */
    public synchronized StateMachine<States,Events> getStateMachine(String machineId) throws Exception {
        if (stateMachine == null) {
            stateMachine = stateMachineService.acquireStateMachine(machineId);
            stateMachine.addStateListener(listener);
            stateMachine.start();
        } else if (!ObjectUtils.nullSafeEquals(stateMachine.getId(), machineId)) {
            stateMachineService.releaseStateMachine(stateMachine.getId());
            stateMachine.stop();
            stateMachine = stateMachineService.acquireStateMachine(machineId);
            stateMachine.addStateListener(listener);
            stateMachine.start();
        }
        return stateMachine;
    }
}
```

When I send a request for initialize a state machine, getting an error like:

```
Unable to persist stateMachineContext
Caused by: org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: ids for this class must be manually assigned before calling save(): org.springframework.statemachine.data.jpa.JpaRepositoryStateMachine
    at org.hibernate.id.Assigned.generate(Assigned.java:33) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:119) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:192) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:135) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:62) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:800) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:785) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_222]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_222]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_222]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_222]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:350) ~[spring-orm-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy117.persist(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_222]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_222]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_222]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_222]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:309) ~[spring-orm-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy117.persist(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save(SimpleJpaRepository.java:535) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar:2.1.10.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_222]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_222]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_222]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_222]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:359) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar:2.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:200) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar:2.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:644) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar:2.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:608) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar:2.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$invoke$3(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:595) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar:2.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:595) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar:2.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:59) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.10.RELEASE.jar:2.1.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:295) ~[spring-tx-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98) ~[spring-tx-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139) ~[spring-tx-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    ... 111 common frames omitted
```

The state of the machine seems to changed, but could not persist on db. As I said, the problem is my curator configuration. Because it works fine when I define connectString with single Zookeeper like
`.connectString("localhost:2181")`

I'm new to Zookeeper and Curator, and open to any help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is a Spring issue and nothing to do with ZooKeeper or Curator. The exception has something to do with Spring and Hibernate.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with this configuration:

```
.withConfiguration()
                .autoStartup(true);
```

Because it tries to start the machine, before having a machine id.